# Why can Python 3.11 parse this ISO datetime but Python 3.9 can't?

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

On the same input `datetime.fromisoformat` succeeds in Python 3.11 but fails in Python 3.9.  Did the ISO format change between minor versions of Python?  If so, what changed?

```
Python 3.11.3 (main, Jun  5 2023, 09:32:32) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2022-11-21T19:44:27.292977Z')
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 21, 19, 44, 27, 292977, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

```
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jun 26 2023, 03:30:25)
[GCC 13.1.1 20230429] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2022-11-21T19:44:27.292977Z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2022-11-21T19:44:27.292977Z'
```

Comment: The ISO format itself didn't change, but Python did. Read the docs: [_"Changed in version 3.11: Previously, this method only supported formats that could be emitted by `date.isoformat()` or `datetime.isoformat()`."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) See also https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#datetime.